# How to programmatically get the location where npm installs global modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I want to programmatically find out the folder where npm installs global modules. This question is similar, but the answer doesn't work for globally installed modules: [How to get details of npm installed modules programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899403/how-to-get-details-of-npm-installed-modules-programatically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the nodejs website:

> globally - This drops modules in {prefix}/lib/node_modules, and puts executable files in {prefix}/bin, where {prefix} is usually something like /usr/local. It also installs man pages in {prefix}/share/man, if they’re supplied.

To get the prefix enter:

```
npm config get prefix
```

Edit:

To do it from node use the npm npm module. Something like this will work:

```
var npm = require("npm")
var myConfigObject = {}
npm.load(myConfigObject, function (er) {
    if (er) return handleError(er)
    console.log(npm.get('prefix'));
})
```

Comment: Thank you sir! Now if I could only figure out how load the global npm module so I could get the correct prefix from javascript rather than from a command execution, I'd be all set!

Comment: So actually tho, mine was in <prefix>/node_modules - there is no lib or bin folder for me. I'm on windows.

Comment: There's an npm module for npm. Maybe this could help.

Comment: Tried it. Unfortuantely A) the version you wrote up there won't work (it should be `npm.prefix`), and B) the prefix it returns is the prefix of the local module installation, not the global installation

Comment: Another note, it looks like they did it slightly differently on windows than linux. The global modules are installed at <prefix>/node_modules in widows, whereas they're installed at <prefix>/lib/node_modules in linux.

Comment: module.paths.push(<prefix>/node_modules)

Answer (score 4):

NPM's primary job is "to put things on your computer."  Their [folders documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders) details what it puts where

Due to differences between operating systems, the `.npmrc` config, and the [`prefix`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/prefix.html) property, it's easiest to rely on npm to determine the global install directory by using [`npm root`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/root.html) like this:

```sh
$ npm root -g
```

You can [execute a command line binary with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20643470/1366033) like this:

```js
const { exec } = require('child_process')
const { promisify } = require('util');

async function main() {
    let execAsync = promisify(exec);
    let { stdout: globalPath } = await execAsync("npm root -g");
    console.log(globalPath);
}
```

---

Alternatively, in order to access the npm module programmatically, you'll need to install it locally:

```sh
$ npm i npm --save
```

And then you can run the following code:

```js
const npm = require("npm")
const { promisify } = require('util');

async function main() {
    await promisify(npm.load)()
    let globalPath = npm.root
    console.log(globalPath)
}
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [Where does npm install packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5926672/1366033)
- [Global npm install location on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33819757/1366033)

Comment: Sadly the programmatic API for NPM was removed in NPM 8.0

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to depend on npm:

```
const { resolve } = require('path')    
const globalPath = resolve(process.execPath, '../../lib/node_modules')
```

Comment: This won't work when the "prefix" property is set, making global node_modules live somewhere else.

Comment: Don't think this works for [global npm install location on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33819757/1366033)