# Global npm install location on windows?

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, pycharm

I'm not 100% sure, but I believe I installed node v5 from the windows installer on both my home and office PCs.

On my home PC global installs happen under %APPDATA%:

```
(dev) go|c:\srv> which lessc
c:\users\bjorn\appdata\roaming\npm\lessc
c:\users\bjorn\appdata\roaming\npm\lessc.cmd
```

while on my office PC, they go under program files:

```
(dev) go|w:\srv> which lessc
c:\program files\nodejs\lessc
c:\program files\nodejs\lessc.cmd
```

I need to provide the full path to a number of these global tools to PyCharm's file watcher, and since the project file i shared it would make sense to not have global resources under a user folder.

Why would the global installs end up in different folders, and how can I force them to a location that is common to all team members?

Comment: 3 years later, I had a similar mystery. The answer turned out to be that node had created a junction at c:\program files\nodejs, which actually pointed to %appdata%\nvm\v8.10.0. So it gave the illusion that might fit what you saw.

Comment: The c:\program files\nodejs symlink turned out to be an artifact of [nvm](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

According to: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders

> - Local install (default): puts stuff in ./node_modules of the current    package root.
> - Global install (with -g): puts stuff in /usr/local or wherever node is    installed.
> - Install it locally if you're going to require() it.
> - Install it globally if you're going to run it on the command line.  -> If you need both, then install it in both places, or use npm link.
>
> #### prefix Configuration
>
> The prefix config defaults to the location where node is installed. On
> most systems, this is `/usr/local`. **On windows, this is the exact
> location of the node.exe binary**.

The docs might be a little outdated, but they explain why global installs can end up in different directories:

```
(dev) go|c:\srv> npm config ls -l | grep prefix
; prefix = "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs" (overridden)
prefix = "C:\\Users\\bjorn\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"
```

Based on the other answers, it may seem like the override is now the default location on Windows, and that I may have installed my office version prior to this override being implemented.

This also suggests a solution for getting all team members to have globals stored in the same absolute path relative to their PC, i.e. (run as Administrator):
**(Run this in `cmd`, not in PowerShell!)**

```
mkdir %PROGRAMDATA%\npm
setx PATH "%PROGRAMDATA%\npm;%PATH%" /M
npm config set prefix %PROGRAMDATA%\npm
```

open a new cmd.exe window and reinstall all global packages.

Explanation (by lineno.):

1. Create a folder in a sensible location to hold the globals (Microsoft is
   adamant that you shouldn't write to ProgramFiles, so %PROGRAMDATA% seems
   like the next logical place.
2. The directory needs to be on the path, so use `setx .. /M` to set the
   system path (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE).  This is what requires you to run
   this in a shell with administrator permissions.
3. Tell `npm` to use this new path. (Note: folder isn't visible in %PATH% in
   this shell, so you must open a new window).

Comment: *Warning:* for some reason the command `setx PATH "%PROGRAMDATA%\npm;%PATH%" /M` will not prepend a new value, but will replace everything (In PowerShell).

Comment: as of today's location for Linux exact area is: `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`

Answer (score 78):

These are typical npm paths if you install a package globally:

```
Windows XP -             %USERPROFILE%\Application Data\npm\node_modules
Newer Windows Versions - %AppData%\npm\node_modules
or -                     %AppData%\roaming\npm\node_modules
```

Comment: Hmm.. `%APPDATA%` is under a user folder, and PyCharm doesn't seem to accept environment variables, so I guess this is a no-go then.

Comment: this is wrong fix your answer
 ~/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules
$ npm
/c/Users/Phil/AppData/Roaming/npm/npm: line 12: node: command not found

Comment: From installing the package globally through Powershell, a generic file, a `cmd_auto_file` file and a `Windows PowerShell Script` file was created in `"$env:APPDATA\npm"`

Answer (score 26):

Just press windows button and type %APPDATA% and type enter.

Above is the location where you can find \npm\node_modules folder. This is where global modules sit in your system.

Comment: If you look at my question you'll find that your assertion is false. The global modules can also be installed under `%PROGRAMFILES%\nodejs`, which is my first question (why do they end up in different folders on my home/office PCs?).  The context of my question (as is stated..) is that I need to provide the path to these globally npm installed tools to the PyCharm IDE, in order for other team members to benefit from me setting it up correctly for our projects. Since (a) PyCharm doesn't allow env vars when specifying executable, and (b) `%APPDATA%=c:\Users\bjorn\..` I can't use APPDATA here.

Answer (score 5):

As of today, global packages installed like for eg. `npm i -g @vue/cli` are by default store in a directory:

```
C:\Users\<YourUserName>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to find out where npm is installing your global module (the title of this thread), look at the output when running `npm install -g sample_module`

> $ npm install -g sample_module **C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\sample_module** ->
>   C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sample_module\bin\sample_module.js
>   + sample_module@5.1.0 updated 1 package in 2.821s

Comment: The question is the entire question, not just the title. I don't think this is an answer to my question.

Comment: @thebjorn I don't think your question title is specific enough, and hence people like me will find it who are looking for the npm install location, not looking for how to change it or why there are different folders, etc.

Comment: The accepted answer contains the answer to your question: `npm config ls -l | grep prefix`, and even if it didn't, the correct procedure would be to ask a new more narrowly focused question...

Comment: Definitely not easier, since you have to install something instead of just look something up (which makes it unusable e.g. for shell/bat scripts).

Comment: It is if you're trying to figure out where your global modules are being put during installs (like as was my case and probably others' who will find this question based on its current title).

Comment: Again, that's your question (which is better solved by the `where` command), it is not what this question is about. This is not an answer to my question.

Comment: I found my answer helpful and I hope others will as well (given the broad title of the OP's question)..

Comment: Of course you found your answer helpful to _your_ question ("where did npm -g install a package on _my_ machine").  That is an entirely different question however, and you should delete this answer, ask that as a new question, and self-answer it. Adding random facts to a 3+ year old question is not the right thing to do.  Also, _all_ of the 3 previous answers mention the `%APPDATA%` path, so you're not even adding anything new..?

Comment: @thebjorn in windows command line would be `> npm config ls -l | findstr prefix`

Comment: Thanks @asam. I forget that not everyone has downloaded gnuwin32 ;-) (https://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score -1):

here is how I install react globally on windows,

npm install -g react

and I can see package installed at,

C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules

Answer (score -1):

I install node v14.9.0 using nvm and I find it in the D drive: `D:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.9.0\node64.exe`.