# Correcting Version of Typescript on Windows 7 Machine

Tags: windows, typescript

I am trying to update my version of TypeScript on a Windows 7 machine.  On a command line,

> tsc --version

gives me:

> Version 1.0.3.0

I went to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript and I see one folder that says "1.0".  The TypeScript Web site says version 2.6 is available.  To get it, it tells me to run

> npm install -g typescript

The command runs with no errors but that "1.0" folder remains.  What is really going on?  Does Node Package Manager have a different TypeScript folder somewhere else?  How do I add a more current folder to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: But what does `tsc —version` return after updating?

Comment: tsc --version says the same thing as before: Version 1.0.3.0

Answer (score 0):

`npm install -g typescript` is going to install TypeScript to your NodeJS global packages folder. On Windows this is probably going to be [`%AppData%\npm\node_modules`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40552409/2225281).

I'm not sure how you ended up with a `Microsoft SDKs` folder, but whatever you did to create it can be done to update it. Basically `npm`'s `tsc` is different than `Microsoft SDKs`'s `tsc`.

Comment: I think that folder is created by Visual Studio Code. This question has some more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39668731/what-typescript-version-is-visual-studio-code-using-how-to-update-it