# I can ONLY install an npm package globally

Tags: node.js, windows

This is me trying to pull a package with regular install:

```
PS C:\temp> npm install aws-sam-local

> aws-sam-local@0.2.4 postinstall C:\temp\node_modules\aws-sam-local
> go-npm install

Downloading from URL: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-local/releases/download/v0.2.4/sam_0.2.4_windows_amd64.tar.gz
fs.js:766
  return binding.rename(pathModule._makeLong(oldPath),
                 ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\temp\node_modules\aws-sam-local\bin\sam.exe' -> 'C:\temp\node_modul
es\aws-sam-local\node_modules\.bin\sam.exe'
    at Object.fs.renameSync (fs.js:766:18)
    at C:\temp\node_modules\go-npm\bin\index.js:62:12
    at C:\temp\node_modules\go-npm\bin\index.js:51:9
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:267:7)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:346:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\temp\package.json'
npm WARN temp No description
npm WARN temp No repository field.
npm WARN temp No README data
npm WARN temp No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! aws-sam-local@0.2.4 postinstall: `go-npm install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the aws-sam-local@0.2.4 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\meee\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-01-19T16_14_18_418Z-debug.log
```

With global:

```
PS C:\temp> npm install --global aws-sam-local

> aws-sam-local@0.2.4 postinstall C:\Users\meee\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-sam-local
> go-npm install

Downloading from URL: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-local/releases/download/v0.2.4/sam_0.2.4_windows_amd64.tar.gz
+ aws-sam-local@0.2.4
added 72 packages in 48.359s
```

Why is this broken and how can I pull this package to a specific folder that all users can access? I guess some of my confusion is what "global" even means here because its still installing it to MY user's folders.

Comment: `no such file or directory, open 'C:\temp\package.json'` Maybe because of this?

Comment: So why global work? I don't understand what the difference is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no *package.json*: `no such file or directory, open 'C:\temp\package.json'`

To install packages locally you need a *package.json* in your working directory to keep track of your local dependencies. You can create a *package.json* with [`npm init`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init).

Read [here](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/) to get an understanding about global and local packages:

> **globally** - This drops modules in `{prefix}/lib/node_modules`, and puts
>   executable files in `{prefix}/bin`, where `{prefix}` is usually something
>   like `/usr/local`. It also installs man pages in `{prefix}/share/man`, if
>   they’re supplied.
>
> **locally** - This installs your package in the current
>   working directory. Node modules go in `./node_modules`, executables go
>   in `./node_modules/.bin/`, and man pages aren’t installed at all.

And also [How to Install Global Packages?](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-globally) and [How to Install Local Packages?](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-locally)

**Edit:**

- Use `npm list -g --depth=0` to list all global packages
- [aws-sam-local](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sam-local) should be installed globally with `npm install -g aws-sam-local`
- [Global npm install location on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33819757/global-npm-install-location-on-windows) and [Folder Structures Used by npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders)

Comment: where is my global package.json on windows?

Comment: Right but I assume there is some global package.json which is why the global command is not failing? Where is that global package config? If I go into my global location `C:\Users\mee\AppData\Roaming\npm` I see individual package.json files for each module. How can global create those for me but running the command non-globally cannot? Does global automate the process of running npm init?

Comment: Mmh. Good question. I searched a lot but couldn't find further information about how npm keep track of global packages.