# Forever is not recognized as a internal or external command

Tags: node.js, forever

Basically i'm a linux user. For the first time i'm running my node.js application in windows machine. I want to run my application as background process.

So installed `forever` globally `npm install forever -g`. Now i tried to run my node application using `forever start app.js.`

I am receiving error as `forever is not reconised as internal or external command`.

I tried setting the `ENV` varibales pointing to `bin` folder of forever. But still im getting the error.

```
OS:Windows 7
```

Please share your ideas.

**Package.Json**

```
{
"Name":"xxxx",
"version":"1.0.0",
"dependencies":{
     "async":"^2.5.0",
     "forever":"^0.15.3"
}
}

Node version: 8.9.3
npm version:5.5.1
```

Comment: have you changed the node version before running **forever start**??

Comment: put your package file also

Comment: @deepak thomas why i have to change the version???

Comment: @AshishChoudhary see my edited post..

Comment: whats your current node version??

Comment: did you use nvm to manage your node versions??

Comment: before running forever check the nodejs version

Comment: So obvious thing to check is making sure you've relaunched the command window (common problem on Windows where environment variables don't reload). Second thing would be to check the [global NPM bin folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33819757/global-npm-install-location-on-windows) and verify you can see Forever in there.

Comment: @James I did that i relaunched the command window. No hope..

Comment: Did you installed it as administrator ? Do you run it as administrator ?

Comment: @Subburaj and did you verify the package has been definitely installed globally? Also try installing another package globally e.g. `grunt`, check that this works. Failing that I think it's a clean Node uninstall / reinstall I'm afraid.