# Uninstalling all the files of React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How to uninstall all the file of React Native even the chocolate, node.js, etc. All the Getting Started guides of React Native. Because when I install my React Native it is installed in C:\ I just want to move it in D:\

Comment: https://chocolatey.org/docs/uninstallation
Do you want to move choco, nodejs etc or you want to move a react native project to D:

Comment: I let my choco node js etc in my C. I want to move a react native project in D. If so, is there would be any problem when I'm developing an app? If I move my react native projects in D?

Comment: If you install your cli tools with '-g', it will be available everywhere. e.g. npm install -g react-native-cli. Then you can go to D:/path/path and run react-native commands in your preferred cli.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/understanding-cli

Comment: I do no get it. I'm not a tech guy, can you elaborate step by step? Thanks.

Comment: Btw, I'm using windows.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43398997/2178042

Comment: Do u mean if I install react native cli with "-g" it will be available everywhere? Then I can create react native app in the D:/ disk that I want? I just have to type "cd D:/path/path" then "create-react-native-app AwesomeProject"?

Comment: This is correct. Hopefully you won't have issues with permission etc