# Angular cli is not installing after running code

Tags: angular, cmd

After I have executed the code:

```
npm install -g@angular/cli
```

`ng` commands don't work and my `npm` folder is also empty, it does not contain the angular files.

I have node version 12 and `npm` version above 6.

Comment: Have you installed node js? https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: yes node -v and npm -v are working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that Angular CLI was installed:

```sh
npm list -g --depth=0
```

If `@angular/cli` is not mentioned in the list, try to reinstall it:

```sh
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Then you must be able to create a new project:

```sh
ng new my-dream-app
```

Comment: No @angular cli is not mentioned in the list and after running npm install -g@angular/cli and after that also the list doesn't contain @angular/cli.     Please help i am badly stuck for many days

Comment: after running npm install it says :npm warn user@1.0.0 no description.no repository field.

Comment: and after that audited 273 packages . found 0 vulnerabilities

Comment: it is in the list when running without global i.e npm list --depth=0

Comment: If You have installed CLI locally, You may execute it as `./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng new my-dream-app`.
As for the installing packages globally, I suggest to check - https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-packages-globally

Comment: I executed C:\Users\user\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng new filename   but it says it is not recognized as internal or external command

Comment: The command I wrote must be executed from the same directory as `npm list--depth=0`. Earlier You have mentioned that it shows @angular/cli as installed.
Also, You may check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33819757/global-npm-install-location-on-windows/43398997)

Comment: You may try an alternative way:  
1. create new directory; 2. run `npm init --yes`; 3. open `package.json`;4. in `scipts` section create new script "ng": "ng"; 5. use `ng` as `npm run ng new projectname`