# bash: heroku: command not found

Tags: bash, heroku

I'm using Windows and I'm trying to use heroku in bash and it's not recognizing the command.

I installed it like this

npm i -g heroku

And then I tried

npm install -g heroku-cli

It does not show up in my package.json.

Comment: Still not in my package.json

Comment: I can't use the sudo command because I'm on Windows

Comment: @Hilary, have you [added your NPM global binary directory to your `PATH`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/folders#executables)? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/33819757/354577

Comment: Also, note that NPM installations [are discouraged](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#install-with-npm): "It’s strongly recommended to use one of the other installation methods if possible".